# AJAX request in rails app error: xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I am trying to run an AJAX request that takes my paginated links index and returns the next set of paginated links on request, but I receive this error when the request is issued upon scrolling to the bottom of the page.

```
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );
```

The request appears to be trying to get the second page of my links given the query params below, but returns a 500 error.

```
http://localhost:3000/links?page=2&_=1451357800871
```

Rails logs error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial links/_link with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/jackburum/personal_projects/quotes_app/app/views"
  * "/Users/jackburum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
):
    1: $('#links').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
    2: <% if @posts.next_page %>
    3:   $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@links) %>');
    4: <% else %>
  app/views/links/index.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_links_index_js_erb___2714542505890050790_70114472173520'
```

This still occurs even after I created my _links partial.

This is the code for the script in my `links.coffee.js` file. The code tests out fine when I test with an alert message, but then when I replace the alert message with get script, I get the AJAX error.

```
ready = ->
    jQuery ->
        $(window).scroll ->
            if $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
                    $.getScript($('.pagination next_page').attr('href'))

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does `$('.pagination next_page')` always find an element? If it doesn't, `.attr('href')` will return `undefined`, which `$.getScript()` will likely handle in an odd manner.

Comment: I have not found documentation that explicitly states that it does. I would think that it should at least trigger 4x since my pagination has four pages worth of content, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Check the Rails logs, there should a full trace for the 500 error, which will tell you where's the problem.

Comment: @Jeiwan thanks for that. I just posted the logs error if you have any insights on that

Comment: @Jbur43 The error occurs when this is run: `render(@links)`. It tries to render links array using `links/_link` template, which it cannot find. Does it work, when you click on the next page link manually?

Comment: @Jeiwan yes it does. I also created an _links partial after reading the error that now contains my index.html.erb code, but the error remains the same

Comment: @Jbur43 It should be 'app/views/links/_link.html.erb', singular form. Is this what you have?

Comment: Hey @Jeiwan I just wanted to let you know that changing from plural to singular worked. If you write that as an answer, I will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeiwan I also opened a new question here with an ajax rendering issue I'm having if you have a few minutes to take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514908/infinite-scroll-rails-ajax-request-firing-but-not-displaying-next-paginated-pag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1: $('#links').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
```

> Missing partial links/_link

When you render an array of ActiveRecord models, Rails will deduce partial names by the class of these models and try to load a separate partial for each model object. So in your case the partial will be `links/_link`, and this is exactly what Rails tries to load according to the error message.

> This still occurs even after I created my _links partial

You have a typo here, it should be `_link`, in singular form. This is a partial used to render one distinct link.