# Infinite scroll rails ajax request firing, but not displaying next paginated page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, infinite-scroll, will-paginate

I have a rails app that I am using `will_paginate` for. I am then using `will_paginate` as a basis for infinite scroll. After a lot of trial and error, the request seems to be working, but instead of rendering the next page of content in the app, the request is re-rendering all of my content and displaying it in paginated form again. I have a thought that it is to do with my .each iterator in my partial, but I am not sure exactly.

Below is my partial, controller, js.erb, coffescript, and logs. If anyone can help with a reason why this is not working properly, I would greatly appreciate it!

Logs: you can see that it is getting the next page, and it does that for all 5 pages on each request:

```
Started GET "/links?page=2&_=1451404304001" for ::1 at 2015-12-29 10:51:46 -0500
Processing by LinksController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "_"=>"1451404304001"}
  Link Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links" LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "links"
  Link Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  ORDER BY "links"."cached_votes_score" DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "links"
```

_link.html.erb:

```
    <!-- order links based on total number of votes -->

  <div class="link row clearfix">
    <h2>

    </h2>
    <h2>
      <%= link_to link.title, link %><br>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <%= link_to link.url, link %><br>
    </p>

<!-- acts_as_votable for like_link -->
    <div class="btn-group">
        <%= link_to like_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
          Upvote
          <%= link.get_upvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to dislike_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
          Downvote
          <%= link.get_downvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

index.js.erb:

```
$('#links').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
<% if @links.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @links.next_page %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

link.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
        $(window).scroll ->
            if $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
                    $.getScript($('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href'))
```

links_controller.rb index action:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @links = Link.order(cached_votes_score: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

    respond_to do |format| 
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div class = "sort_paginate_ajax"><%= render @links %></div>

<div id="quotes_links">
  <%= will_paginate @links %>
</div>
```

When I changed my index.js.erb to the change recommended in the first comment by Miles, I now get the following undefined method error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_pages' for 3:Fixnum):
    1: $('#links').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
    2: <% if @links.next_page %>
    3:   $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @links.next_page %>');
    4: <% else %>
    5:   $('.pagination').remove();
    6: <% end %>
```

Comment: Try changing '''$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate links %>');''' to '''$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate links.next_page %>'); ''' with the @ on links. SO made me remove them in my comment

Comment: @MilesStanfield I changed the replaceWith syntax and I now get the new error I just posted above, `undefined method 'total pages'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @links.order(cached_votes_score: :desc).each do |link| %>
```

You don't need to do this, because you're rendering a collection of ActiveRecord models:

```
$('#links').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
```

Rails will iterate over links and render `app/links/_link.html.erb` partial for each link. So this partial should contain only HTML displaying one distinct link. You can use `link` variable inside it.

Also try to not use `order` in views, but do so in a controller action. When you pass an instance variable to a view it should be ready to be used, without additional queries. It's better to keep all queries and logic inside controllers and models and don't mix them into views.

Comment: I tried this `<%= link_to link.title, link %><br>` and `<%= link_to @links.title, link %><br>` this in place of the .each loop, I get an undefined method error for each?

Comment: Hm, this happens because of this: `<div class = "sort_paginate_ajax"><%= render 'link' %></div>` Here you render `_link` partial without passing `link` variable to it. Change this render to `render @links`

Comment: Okay, so that is working now, but I still cannot get the next page to display when it triggers the request

Comment: What happens when you click 'next page'? According to the codes it gets links with offset 5, renders them using `_link` partial and appends the links to `#links` element. But it seems there's no `#links` selector in `index.html.erb`.